# MySQL foreign key constraints not working with my database design

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, orm

I'm making a product price comparison website with using XML imports from other websites. The imported products go into a table called 'products'.

Products contains:
- id
- SKU (product code)
- url
- shopName
- price

I have another table called 'productshop'. Here, the table contains the following values:
- id (PK)
- SKU (foreign key to the product in the 'products' table)
- Shop Display Name

How it works: manually, the administrator adds a productShop entry. The administrator enters the display name of the shop, and the SKU code that is used by that shop. This way, this product is added to the website.

This all works fine, but I'm experiencing the following issue:

When the product table gets updated, it's possible for a shop to temporarily have a product out of stock. That means it's no more in the XML file I receive from them. I don't want to instantly remove the 'productshop' entry either because it is possible that the item becomes available again and then I'd have to add it again manually.

**So basically: I want a productshop to be able to reference a product that might not exist.** It is not possible to delete a product right now when a productShop is referencing it.

Is this bad database design? Should I disable foreign key constraints or is this just a very bad idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading the XML files add them into the table and then when the customer is doing the buying process the product could be not available at the website anymore and consequent not on the XML as well?

If so, I believe you need to work on the website using multi-threading to check if the item is still available or not and if so proceed with the sell.

Another scenario, not sure how often you are updating the database table with the XML, but you could add a row version to the database and check if changes happened and if so you need to check if you still have the product available or not.

Row Version MySQL:
https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?60,367176,367176

Row Version SQL:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I added a row "available" to the product table. When the product isn't in the XML file anymore, available is set to false until it later re-appears in the XML file. I think that is kind of what you meant with the version row? :)

Comment: Correct! Glad I could help! :)